# writeFile does not wait for variable to be instantiated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and javascript in general but I am having issues understanding why the writeFile function is writing a blank file. I think the for loop should be a Promise but I am not sure how to write it.

```
const removeProviders = function () {
    readline.question('Where is the file located?  ', function(filePath) {
        let providerArray = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString().split('\r\n');
        console.log(providerArray);
        let importFile = '';

        for (let providerId in providerArray) {
            getProvider(providerArray[providerId]).then((response) => {
                let providerInfo = response.data;
                return providerInfo;
            }).then((providerInfo) => {
                let entry = createImportEntry(providerInfo);
                importFile += "entry";
            })
        }

        fs.writeFile('C:/path/to/file.txt', importFile);
```

Comment: Your promises are not resolved when you're writing data to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect all the promises from the for-loop into an Array and then pass them into `Promise.all()` which will resolve only after all of them resolved. If one of the promises are rejected, it will reject as well:

```
const promises = providerArray.map((item) => {

  return getProvider(item)
    .then((response) => {
      let providerInfo = response.data;
      return providerInfo;
    })
    .then((providerInfo) => {
      let entry = createImportEntry(providerInfo);
      importFile += "entry";
    });

});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {

  fs.writeFile('C:/path/to/file.txt', importFile, err => {

    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

  });

});
```

While doing this you could also get rid of the `importFile` variable and collect directly the results of your promises. `Promise.all().then(results => {})` will then give you an array of all results. Thus no need for an updatable variable.

Answer (score 1):

The below approach may be useful.
I don't know your getProvider return Promise. you can set promise in getProvider method

```
const getProviderValue = async function(providerArray) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        let importFile = '';
        for (let providerId in providerArray) {
            await getProvider(providerArray[providerId]).then((response) => {
                let providerInfo = response.data;
                return providerInfo;
            }).then((providerInfo) => {
                let entry = createImportEntry(providerInfo);
                importFile += "entry";
            })
        }
        resolve(importFile)
    })
}

const removeProviders = async function () {
    readline.question('Where is the file located?  ', function(filePath) {
        let providerArray = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString().split('\r\n');
        console.log(providerArray);
        let importFile = await getProviderValue(providerArray)
        fs.writeFile('C:/path/to/file.txt', importFile);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop does not wait for the promises to resolve. A better way to approach this problem would be to use reduce.

```
providerArray.reduce(
    (p, _, i) => {
        p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve => 
            getProvider(providerArray[providerId]).then((response) => {
                let providerInfo = response.data;
                return providerInfo;
            }).then((providerInfo) => {
                let entry = createImportEntry(providerInfo);
                importFile += entry;
                resolve();
            }))
        );
    }
, Promise.resolve() );
```

You can also use Promise.all but the out data may not be in the order that you expect if you append to the importFile variable.